# S3: ExpiredToken error for S3 pre-signed url within expiry period

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

This is how I am generating pre-signed url for an S3 object from my python script.

```
s3client = boto3.client("s3")
url = s3client.generate_presigned_url("get_object", Params={"Bucket": args.bucket, "Key": dated_filename}, ExpiresIn=86400)
```

where I am giving an expiry of 24 hours.

When I try to download the file immediately using the url from a browser, it works. But it doesn't work if I try to download it, say after 10-12 hours (I don't know the exact time after which it starts failing).

This is the error I am getting.

```
<Code>ExpiredToken</Code>
<Message>The provided token has expired.</Message>
```

Not sure if it is a bug or I am not doing it the right way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not providing the key information: `args.expiry` or the resulting URL. If the credentials you are using to sign expires in 10-12 hours, then the URL also expires.

Comment: @helloV I believe you nailed it. If the signed URL itself had expired, the error would contain `<Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Request has expired</Message>`.

Comment: @helloV I am giving an expiry of 24 hours. `args.expiry` was just a placeholder for that. Have updated the code with actual value.

Answer (score 35):

Are you running under an IAM role?  A presigned URL is only valid as long as the session key that was used when generating it.  If you are authenticating as an IAM user with long-lived access keys, this is not a problem.  But IAM roles use temporary access keys that cycle every 36 hours.

You know your session key has expired because you are getting the "The provided token has expired." error, which (as noted above) is a different error message than "Request has expired " which you get when the presigned URL reached its expiration date.

Also, presigned URLs have a hard limit of 7 days - but that doesn't seem to be your problem.

Comment: Source: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/presigned-url-s3-bucket-expiration/

Comment: Is there a way to force a session renewal in such a case so that we are 100% sure that the generated signed URL is valid? The only solution I can think of is catching a failure and regenerating a URL, the only problem is that its not always possible when the signed URL is sent to a third party

Comment: @Robert Antonucci Any idea when the IAM role renews? Is it possible that a presignedURL might get created in the last 1 minute before expiry and is hence almost expired the very next minute?

Comment: @Teddy that sounds possible.  The short lived session is created when you first start accessing AWS.  I'm not sure what then happens if you wait 5 minutes and then make another request for a session - I'm not sure if it creates a new session or uses the existing session.  If it's the latter, then you could see pre-signed URLs lasting less than the session time.  But I don't know for sure.

Comment: When using AWS Instance Profile, EC2 metadata provides 6-hour validity tokens in this local network link : 
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/_role_name_/

Also, EC2 doesn't wait for 6 hours to let it expire before providing the next one. 
Every one hour it places a new 6-hour-valid token.
(Seems the token can be 6+ hours.. say 6h 15m or 6h 24m)

So, the EC2 instance will have a STS session validity of at least 5 hours at any point of time.

Comment: If you want to *explicitly* tell Boto3 which access key to use, you can do this with something like `s3client = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=MY_AWS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=MY_SECRET_KEY)` - retrieving those values from somewhere like SSM. 

If you are working in Lambda, the standard Boto3 client constructor will use temporary access keys from STS, which are fine for ephemeral API calls, but will cause expired token problems for long-lived pre-signed URLs. 

Excellent discussion on access keys and Lambda here: https://www.keithrozario.com/2020/06/access-keys-in-aws-lambda.html

Answer (score -2):

It is all about the AWS credentials that you are using see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/presigned-url-s3-bucket-expiration/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31461846)